# Manipulating cell array elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array with elements `"abc"` , `"def"`, `"ghi"`.

Can anyone tell me how can I convert it to `"aa bb cc"`, `"dd ee ff"`, `"gg hh ii"`?

I ended in doing `"abcabc"` and so on.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Also, to clarify, are the elements of your cells `'"abc"'` or `'abc'`? In other words, do they contain the straight double quote symbol `'"'` which is not itself used to create Matlab strings (char arrays)?

Answer (score 4):

How about using regular expresions?

```
x = {'abc', 'def', 'ghi'}; %// cell array of strings
y = regexprep(x, '.', '$0$0 '); %// duplicate each character and insert a blank space
y = regexprep(y, ' $', ''); %// remove last space
```

This gives

```
y = 
    'aa bb cc'    'dd ee ff'    'gg hh ii'
```

Comment: I realize we're not playing code golf (unfortunately? :)) but it's shorter to use `deblank` instead of the last line. `deblank` is also almost an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @transversalitycondition Good idea! Anyway, the other question does that, so I'll leave it like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> t = {'abc','def'}
>> tnew = cellfun(@(x)reshape([x' x' repmat(' ',numel(x),1)]',1,[]),t,'UniformOutput',false)

tnew = 

'aa bb cc '    'dd ee ff '
```

There will be a trailing whitespace after each string but you can get rid of that using strtrim.

```
>> strtrim(tnew)

ans = 

'aa bb cc'    'dd ee ff'
```